# How to create new string in C++ by two other ones?

Tags: c++, string

I want to create `string` `"hello1world` by this two strings:

```
string s1 = "hello"
string s2 = "world"
```

I do this:

```
string my_str;
sprintf(my_str, "%s1%s", s1, s2);
```

But I have an error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)’
     sprintf(my_str, "%s1%s", s1, s2);
```

How to do it properly?

Comment: I recommend you check e.g. [this `std::string` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Look at the overloaded operators. I'm sure you could find something useful to *add* two strings.

Comment: Please get aware of C-functionality and C++-functionality (Your mixture is plain wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use `sprintf`. It only supports `char[]` strings, i.e. C strings. So that's why it doesn't compile when you pass `std::string`.

With `std::string`, a simple `+` is all you need:

```
string my_str = s1 + s2;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concatenate the two strings, you can use `+` operator of `std::string`

```
string s1 = "hello";
string s2 = "world";
string my_str = s1 + "1" + s2;
```

Answer (score 1):

For case of two strings formatting use `operator+=`:

```
std::string myStr(s1 + "1" + s2);
```

If you need to do formatting of many strings, a more efficient way will be:

```
std::string myStr;
myStr.reserve(1048576);      // Reserve space in buffer to prevent reallocation
while (<many iterations>)
{
  myStr.append(s1);
  myStr.append("1");
  // Do more formatting here
  myStr.append(s2);
}
```

If you have some non-string values to include in your result you can use `std::stringstream` from `<sstream>` header:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "hello";
ss << 1;
ss << "world";
std::string myStr(ss.str());
```

I need to mention (thanks @IInspectable for hint) `std::stringstream` is [**pretty slow**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/aiFIGb6za0w). C++11 offers better way for numbers formatting with use of [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: You cannot be serious... -1, sorry.

Comment: @IInspectable I knew that `stringstream` is not very fast, but now i see it's almost 4x slower than `operator+`. Thanks for comment. I've included hint about that in the answer and added more fast approaches.

Comment: I wasn't actually commenting on the performance. Performance varies across implementations anyway. Suggesting string streams to concatenate strings, however, is just so utterly convoluted, and non-intuitive, that I cannot imagine the confusion of the mind suggesting such. At any rate, I revoked the down-vote after your update.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree, original post doesn't properly reflect my idea, I proposed `stringstream` for case when non-string values should be included into result. The reason of it is `1` in the format string `"%s1%s"`. I thought it would be useful to print something other than strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s3 = s1 + "1" + s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have many things to do you can use operator +

```
string a = "hello";
string b = "world";
string ans = a + "1" + b;
```

you can use string::append

```
  string a = "hello";
  string b = "world";
  string ans = "";
  ans.append(a);
  ans.append("1");
  ans.append(b);
```

you can use insert but not pereferd in concate better use + operator or append

```
string a = "hello";
string b = "world";
a.insert(a.size(),1,'1');
a.insert(a.size(),b);
```

insert with a string use it as string::insert(index,string);

 with characters use it as string::insert(index,len,char);

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't address the question. The question is asking for help creating a **new** string object out of existing string objects.

Comment: ok I give 2 answers one using append the other one using operator +
which uses a new string to concatenate it and give a third solution which is insert to make many options ?

Comment: You copied in someone else's answer, while I was writing my comment. Now that's really pathetic.

Comment: no, i don't do that ?!!!!